# Swift 3: Is there a way to cast an object to a class and protocol at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift-protocols, existential-type

I've read through the relevant sections of Apple's Swift iBook (Type Casting & Protocols) but I can seem to find a way to specify that an object is an instance of a particular class that conforms to a specific protocol.

As an example in `tableView(_: , cellForRowAt: )` I would like to cast the cell returned by `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseID, for: indexPath)` as being a subclass of `UITableViewCell` that conforms to the `RLMEntityCapableCell` protocol (Just specifies that conformers have a variable called `item` that is an instance of `Object`, or one of its subclasses).

This route works but the *double casting* seems excessive:

```
protocol RLMEntityCapableCell: class  {
     var item: Object { get set }
}

 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseID, for: indexPath) as! RLMEntityCapableCell // Cast here so we can set item
    cell.item = items[indexPath.row]
    return cell as! UITableViewCell // Cast again so the return type is right…
}
```

This other approach:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseID, for: indexPath) 
           as! RLMEntityCapableCell, UITableViewCell
```

gives this error:

> type annotation missing in pattern

so clearly isn't the right way to do it either.

I would prefer to specify that in order to conform to the protocol an object has to inherit from either `UITableViewCell` or `UICollectionViewCell` but the base of a protocol can only be limited to the class type and no further.

#### Edit:

The idea here is to have a generic data source for Realm objects that leverages generics much like `Array` and `Dictionary` do. The cells used in each table view would be specific to the entity to be displayed but the data source would only know that the cell would be a subclass of `UITableViewCell` that conforms to `RLMEntityCapableCell`. All the data source needs to worry about is telling the cell what instance (that would always be a subclass of `Object`) it needs to display, the cell would take it from there and configure itself as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this isn't possible... *yet*.

The next Swift release (version 4) might bring what you are looking for, a new feature called **[Class and Subtype Existentials](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md)**:

> This proposal brings more expressive power to the type system by allowing Swift to represent *existentials* of classes and subtypes which *conform* to protocols.
>
> The proposal keeps the existing `&` syntax but allows one of the elements to be either `AnyObject` or of class type (e.g., `SomeClass & SomeProtocol`).

You could then say:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseID, for: indexPath) 
           as! UITableViewCell & RLMEntityCapableCell
```

But, of course, you won't be able to use this to add a *superclass requirement* to your `RLMEntityCapableCell` protocol (as you initially wished). We may need to wait for Swift 5 for that :)

---

Some other examples using the above **Class and Subtype Existentials** (Swift 4) feature:

```
protocol P {}
struct S {}
class C {}
class D : P {}
class E : C, P {}

let u: S & P // Compiler error: S is not of class type
let v: C & P = D() // Compiler error: D is not a subtype of C
let w: C & P = E() // Compiles successfully
```

and:

```
protocol P {}
class C {}
class D : C { }
class E : C { }
class F : D, P { }

let t: C & D & P = F() // Okay: F is a subclass of D and conforms to P
let u: D & P = t       // Okay: D & P is equivalent to C & D & P
let v: C & D & P = u   // Okay: C & D & P is equivalent to D & P
let w: D & E & P       // Compiler error: D is not a subclass of E or vice-versa
```

Comment: I had a feeling the answer was 'it can't be done' but at least there is hope for the future. I'm not trying to add a superclass requirement though, just trying to build a truly generic data source for Realm. The specific subclass of `UITableViewCell` that will be used isn't known to the data source only that it will be a subclass that conforms to the protocol.

Comment: @theMikeSwan Yeah, all is not lost and Swift 4 is just around the corner :) But reading again your (updated) question it really feels like you are after a superclass requirement: *.. the data source would only know that the cell would be a **subclass** of `UITableViewCell` that conforms to `RLMEntityCapableCell`*. The aforementioned superclass requirement would then be the `UITableViewCell` class...

Comment: ...such requirement could be specified as `protocol RLMEntityCapableCell: UITableViewCell {...}`. BTW, I would love to have this feature as well!

Answer (score -1):

`UITableViewCell` doesn't have an `item` property, so what you probably want to do is create a subclass of it that conforms to your protocol, and then cast `cell` as that.

```
protocol RLMEntityCapableCell: class  {
    var item: Object { get set }
}

class RLMCell: UITableViewCell, RLMEntityCapableCell {
    var item: Object
}

 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseID, for: indexPath) as? RLMCell ?? RLMCell() 
    cell.item = items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Notes:
1. `dequeueReusableCell` returns an optional and will almost certainly return nil in some cases, so don't force unwrap it.
2. You'll need to do at least one of the following: make `item` optional, provide a default value, or add an initializer function.

Comment: I'm working on making a generic data source so the specific subclass of `UITableViewCell` is not known to the class, only that it will be a cell that conforms to the protocol.

Comment: @theMikeSwan I assume you're going to be casting it to your protocol when you want to access the `item` property.  In that case, it doesn't matter what the specific subclass is as long as it conforms to the protocol.

Comment: The edit I added may clarify my objective. The double casting I have now should work, I just wanted to do all the casting once for clarity.

Comment: @theMikeSwan Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, but "the cell would be a subclass of `UITableViewCell` that conforms to `RLMEntityCapableCell`" is literally exactly what my answer does.

Comment: Except it depends on the code in the class knowing _which_ `UITableViewCell` subclass is going to be used. Because I'm using generics the class doesn't know what class the cell is going to be otherwise your answer would be exactly what is needed. If this was Objective-C I would have used `UITableViewCell<RLMEntityCapableCell>` and the compiler would know it was going to be a subclass of `UITableViewCell` that conforms to `RLMEntityCapableCell`.

Comment: @theMikeSwan What are you talking about?  The entire point of a protocol is that you don't need to know where it's coming from. `cell as RLMEntityCapableCell` will return a valid object as long as it conforms to the protocol, regardless of the specific subclass.